# JTextField not editable with JFrame as parent, JWindow making method unpaintable

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
private JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
private JWindow hsWindow = new JWindow(frame);

hsWindow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
    JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
    JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Enter your name: ");
    JTextField txtName = new JTextField();
hsWindow.add(btnSave);
hsWindow.add(btnCancel);
hsWindow.add(lblName);
hsWindow.add(txtName);
     
hsWindow.setVisible(true);
hsWindow.setFocusable(true);
hsWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
     
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
         hsName = txtName.getText();
         saveHighScores();
         hsWindow.setVisible(false);
         hsWindow.setFocusable(false);
         txtName.setText("");
         setHighScores();
         gameOver(g);
    }
});
```

Can someone tell me why the JTextField is not editable?
The field itself is there, but I cannot type in it.

Also, when I call my method *gameOver(g)* without the *JWindow* appearing, everything is fine. However, if I have the *JWindow* appear and call it after pushing the button, my *gameOver* method is not properly painted.
Why is that?

Here is the important parts of the gameOver method

```
private void gameOver(Graphics g){
  int z = 25;
  score = dots - 3; //The amount of apples collected = your score
  String msg = "Game Over";
  String scoreS = "Final Score : " + score; //Displaying score
  Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
  Font smallnb = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 12);
  FontMetrics metric = getFontMetrics(small); //FontMetrics is easier to use to position text
  g.setColor(Color.white);
  g.setFont(small);
  
  //Centers and Draws the Messages
  g.drawString(msg, (WIDTH - metric.stringWidth(msg)) / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
  g.drawString(scoreS, (WIDTH - metric.stringWidth(scoreS)) / 2, ((HEIGHT / 2) - 30));
  
  //Drawing High Scores
  metric = getFontMetrics(smallnb);
  g.setFont(smallnb);
  g.setColor(Color.red);
  for(String line : str.split("\n")){
     g.drawString(line, (WIDTH - metric.stringWidth(str)) - 110, z += 
     g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
  }
```